# How to move the section plane with a mouse wheel event

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

One of our users has this request to mimic the user experience of a different software.

Currently we create a section plane and move the yellow arrow with the mouse.
Is it possible to move the created section plane in the direction of the arrow, with a key combination (shift + mouse scroll event).

If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the current section plane programatically, like so:

```js
function moveSectionPlaneByDelta(viewer, delta) {
    // Assuming that section tool is active
    const sectionTool = viewer.toolController.getActiveTool();
    const sectionPlanes = sectionTool.getSectionPlanes();
    if (sectionPlanes.length === 1) {
        const normal = new THREE.Vector3(sectionPlanes[0].x, sectionPlanes[0].y, sectionPlanes[0].z);
        const position = normal.clone().multiplyScalar(-sectionPlanes[0].w + delta);
        sectionTool.setSectionPlane(normal, position);
    }
}

// ...

moveSectionPlaneByDelta(viewer, 5.0); // move in the direction of the plane normal
moveSectionPlaneByDelta(viewer, -5.0); // move against the direction of the plane normal
```